# Missing recovery mode on Android?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, recovery-mode, factory-reset, boot-loop, fastboot

I can't hard reset my Android phone it seems like my recovery mode is missing what should I do to make it back to normal or default? I already tried to perform hard reset but it only reboot to menu.
My phone is O+ 8.38z
Android version 5.0
It is still working
But i can't access fastboot and recovery mode

Comment: Welcome Android Enthusiasts! What is your phone model and Android version?

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody can help you without any information about phone model, android version, phone state (is it working? reason for factory reset?) what exactly you have tried (steps to reproduce?) Why do you think recovery mode is missing, are there any error messages? What menu (picture?)

Comment: I already edited my question

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-hard-reset-an-O+-3-38z-android-phone-easily there is one extra step required after selecting recovery mode